# Window_Load event in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, window-load

I need to write some functions to be executed during the window_load() in WPF-MVVM. Every button will have their own command to be executed. Whereas is there any command available for window_load() event in MVVM Model ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You will have to use interactions to do that i.e to invoke command on event.

```
<Window
    xmlns:intr="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
>
    <intr:Interaction.Triggers>
        <intr:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding WindowLoaded}"/>
        </intr:EventTrigger>
    </intr:Interaction.Triggers>
    <!-- the rest of your XAML here -->
</Window>
```

Window.Interactivity namespace has EventTrigger and InvokeCommandAction.

Don't forget that the `WindowLoaded` is a property.

`public ICommand WindowLoaded { get; set; }`

You later have to create new RelayCommand/RoutedUICommand to actually receive the callback.

Thanks

Comment: Is it needed to add it in .XAML file...? or anywhere else ? Iam neew to it... Can u help me some more briefly...!!!!

Comment: yes you need to put in xaml like this <Window> <intr:Interaction.Triggers>
        <intr:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding WindowLoaded}"/>
        </intr:EventTrigger>
    </intr:Interaction.Triggers></Window>

Comment: also you need to define xmlns:intr="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

Comment: Where do i find the Window.Interactivity namespace ? have to be downloaded ?

Comment: you will have to install expression blend sdk.. here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It works only within a control and not for "Window Load". Any idea where i could be wrong.?

Comment: You can actually install the System.Windows.Interactivity from a nuget package.