# How to bind distinct query results to a combobox and pass it as selected cells value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have tried numerous Stack Overflow answers but I just cannot find a straight-forward easy example of what I am hoping to achieve.

I am attempting to fill a combo box with distinct results from a table (dimDate) and also change that combo box selection when the grid row is selected (from safety table).

Needless to say what I kept trying does not work as expected. What am I doing wrong, and how can I get around it with the simplest working example?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Label Content="Year" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="txtyr" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
            Width="115" SelectedIndex="0" DisplayMemberPath="Year"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Years}" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=years_SelectedValue}" 
            SelectedValuePath="value">
</ComboBox>

<Label Content="Quarter" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="txtqt" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
            Width="115" SelectedIndex="0" DisplayMemberPath="Year"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Quarters}" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=quarters_SelectedValue}" 
            SelectedValuePath="value"/>

<Label Content="Name" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="txtnm" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="2"
            Width="115" SelectedIndex="0" DisplayMemberPath="Year"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=names_SelectedValue}" 
            SelectedValuePath="value"/>

<Label Content="Safery Score:" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
<Controls:NumericUpDown x:Name="txtssc"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                        Controls:TextBoxHelper.HasText="True" Width="115" Height="20" 
                        Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Score"
                        UpDownButtonsWidth="25" Maximum="10" Minimum="-10" HasDecimals="False" 
                        InterceptArrowKeys="True" InterceptMouseWheel="True"                         
                        />

<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource lowCase}" x:Name="dtGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CanUserResizeRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" GridLinesVisibility="All" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="false" SelectedCellsChanged="dtGrid_SelectedCellsChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Year}" Header="Year"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quarter}" Header="Quarter"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SafetyScore}" Header="Safety Score"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
namespace Safety
{
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new SafetyViewModel();
            string connectionString = "data Source=xxx; initial catalog=xxx; user id=xxx; password=xxx";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ID, Year, Quarter, Name, SaferyScore from MATRIX.dbo.Safety", connection);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                dtGrid.DataContext = dt;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        private void dtGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView row_selected = dtGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
            if (row_selected == null) return;
            txtyr.ItemsSource = row_selected["Year"].ToString();
            txtqt.Text = row_selected["Quarter"].ToString();
            txtnm.Text = row_selected["Name"].ToString();
            txtscc.Value = Convert.ToInt16(row_selected["SafetyScore"].ToString());
            txtID.Text = row_selected["ID"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**SafetyViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Safety.Model;
using System.Windows;
using Safety;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Safety.ViewModel
{
    public class SafetyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public SafetyViewModel()
        {
            this.loadyearlist();
            this.loadnamelist();
            this.loadquarterslist();
        }

        public void loadyearlist()
        {
            using (MATRIXEntities db = new MATRIXEntities())
            {
                var yrs = (from a in db.dimDate
                         select a).Distinct()
                         .ToList();

                Years = new ObservableCollection<dimDate>(yrs);
            }
        }

        public void loadquarterslist()
        {
            using (MATRIXEntities db = new MATRIXEntities())
            {
                var qts = (from a in db.dimDate
                           select a).Distinct()
                         .ToList();

                Quarters = new ObservableCollection<dimDate>(qts);
            }
        }

        public void loadnamelist()
        {
            using (MATRIXEntities db = new MATRIXEntities())
            {
                var nms = (from a in db.Employees
                         select a)
                         .ToList();

                Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employees>(nms);
            }
        }



        private ObservableCollection<dimDate> years;
        public ObservableCollection<dimDate> Years
        {
            get { return years; }
            set
            {
                years = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Years");
            }
        }

        public string _years_SelectedValue;
        private string years_SelectedValue
        {
            get { return _years_SelectedValue; }
            set
            {
                _years_SelectedValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("years_SelectedValue");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<dimDate> quarters;
        public ObservableCollection<dimDate> Quarters
        {
            get { return quarters; }
            set
            {
                quarters = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Quarters");
            }
        }

        public string _quarters_SelectedValue;
        private string quarters_SelectedValue
        {
            get { return _quarters_SelectedValue; }
            set
            {
                _quarters_SelectedValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("quarters_SelectedValue");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Employees> employees;
        public ObservableCollection<Employees> Employees
        {
            get { return employees; }
            set
            {
                employees = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Employees");
            }
        }

        public string _names_SelectedValue;
        private string names_SelectedValue
        {
            get { return _names_SelectedValue; }
            set
            {
                _names_SelectedValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("names_SelectedValue");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
            => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace Safety.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class dimDate
    {
        public int DateID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Day { get; set; }
        public int Quarter { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Safety.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Safety
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Quarter { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int SafetyScore { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Safety.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Employees
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are mixing both `ViewModel` and `CodeBehind` either do all in `ViewModel` or in `CodeBehind` 
if ViewModel then you can use the `SelectedItem` of `DataGrid` to find which item is selected and based on that set the `ComboBox SelectedItem`.

Comment: check [this](https://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)

Comment: What exactly is your issue here? Please provide a small reproducible example.

Comment: @mm8 Thanks for the help. The binding does not work properly and he selectedcellschangedevent does not fire for the combo boxes. Nothing happens. I can't see how I can make it smaller than this without losing context, maybe remove loadnamelist() from the viewmodel and a combo box but that would be it.

Comment: @iCosmin You might consider getting rid of unnecessary positioning markup, like margins, Grid.Rows, etc. Also using statements I think can be cut.

Comment: Does the datagrid bind show data at all? You set it's datacontext to a datatable and bind it's itemssource using just binding. I recommend you take a look at using an orm. Put dapper top of your list. Return a strongly typed collection and translate that to an observablecollection of row viewmodels. Do all that in your window viewmodel.

Comment: Querying your database from the view is the exact opposite of MVVM. The view should get all it's data from the view model, who in turn should ask a repo or a service. As @Andy points out, at the very least you'd want your view model collections to be typed, then you can compare the selected item of your datagrid with the items bound to the combobox in a structured way.

Comment: @Andy Yes, it shows data. I know how to use and orm, just not in this particular case. Thanks for the suggestion. Can you just show me an example that I can use so I can accept it. I would be grateful for that. Thanks.

Comment: @Funk You're right, I just don't know how to do it correctly. Could you please show me an example so I can fully understand?

Comment: A benefit of separation of concerns is that it enables you to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for each distinct problem. If you don't know how to create a model, or a list of them, from data stored in a DB, then look it up and ask for help when you're stuck. Next you can return to the WPF part providing a sample with dummy data, so people trying to help can actually run it. Setting up an entire layered architecture just to _show you how it's done_ is out of scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Funk I agree with the last part but I don't know what else to list. You have the Model.cs right there. I can't break it out simpler than that because I don't know how. Dummy data can be 2 lines (for year, quarter, name). That's where I am stuck. Are you wiling to help? Telling me what I should do via comment is not helping me a whole lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has lot of problems. Few are listed below:

- Bind Properties should be public instead of private
- In Code behind, you are trying to set the `Text` of ComboBox instead of `SelectedValue`
- You are mixing Code behind with ViewModel design

I've written below code which demonstrates the requirement using MVVM design pattern.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Margin="5" Grid.Column="0">
                <Label Content="Year" />
                <ComboBox x:Name="txtyr"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Years}" 
                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=years_SelectedValue}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Margin="5"  Grid.Column="1">
                <Label Content="Quarter"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="txtqt"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Quarters}" 
                SelectedValue="{Binding Path=quarters_SelectedValue}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Margin="5"  Grid.Column="2">
                <Label Content="Name" />
                <ComboBox x:Name="txtnm"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" 
                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=names_SelectedValue}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dtGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Safeties}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSafety}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Year}" Header="Year"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quarter}" Header="Quarter"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SafetyScore}" Header="Safety Score"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

For demo, I've defined the ViewModel in View.

**MainViewModel.Cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            var data = Model.GetData();
            Safeties.AddRange(data);
            Years.AddRange(data.Select(d => d.Year).Distinct());
            Quarters.AddRange(data.Select(d => d.Quarter).Distinct());
            Names.AddRange(data.Select(d => d.Name).Distinct());
        }

        private ObservableCollection<int> years = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        public ObservableCollection<int> Years
        {
            get { return years; }
        }

        private int _years_SelectedValue;
        public int years_SelectedValue
        {
            get { return _years_SelectedValue; }
            set
            {
                _years_SelectedValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("years_SelectedValue");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<int> quarters = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        public ObservableCollection<int> Quarters
        {
            get { return quarters; }
        }

        private int _quarters_SelectedValue;
        public int quarters_SelectedValue
        {
            get { return _quarters_SelectedValue; }
            set
            {
                _quarters_SelectedValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("quarters_SelectedValue");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> names = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> Names
        {
            get { return names; }
        }

        private string _names_SelectedValue;
        public string names_SelectedValue
        {
            get { return _names_SelectedValue; }
            set
            {
                _names_SelectedValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("names_SelectedValue");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Safety> safeties = new ObservableCollection<Safety>();
        public ObservableCollection<Safety> Safeties
        {
            get { return safeties; }
        }

        private Safety selectedSafety;
        public Safety SelectedSafety
        {
            get { return selectedSafety; }
            set
            {
                selectedSafety = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedSafety));
                if (this.selectedSafety != null)
                {
                    this.years_SelectedValue = selectedSafety.Year;
                    this.quarters_SelectedValue = selectedSafety.Quarter;
                    this.names_SelectedValue = selectedSafety.Name;
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With above code incorporation, the below gif demos how the feature works:

[image]

**Additional code**

To demo, I've created a class to get the Data

```
public static class Model
    {
        public static List<Safety> GetData()
        {
            return new List<Safety>()
            {
                new Safety() { ID = 1, Name = "First", Quarter = 1, SafetyScore = 1, Year = 2001 },
                new Safety() { ID = 2, Name = "Second", Quarter = 2, SafetyScore = 1, Year = 2001 },
                new Safety() { ID = 3, Name = "Third", Quarter = 3, SafetyScore = 1, Year = 2001 },
                new Safety() { ID = 4, Name = "Fourth", Quarter = 4, SafetyScore = 1, Year = 2001 },
                new Safety() { ID = 5, Name = "First", Quarter = 1, SafetyScore = 1, Year = 2002 },
                new Safety() { ID = 6, Name = "Second", Quarter = 2, SafetyScore = 1, Year = 2002 },
                new Safety() { ID = 7, Name = "Third", Quarter = 3, SafetyScore = 1, Year = 2002 },
                new Safety() { ID = 8, Name = "Fourth", Quarter = 4, SafetyScore = 1, Year = 2002 },
            };
        }
    }
```

And extension for AddRange for `ObservableCollection`. However, you can use the ObservableRangeCollection introduced in C#7.0

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
    { 
        public static void AddRange<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> observableCollection, IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                observableCollection.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Safety.cs**

```
public class Safety : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int id;
        public int ID
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChange(nameof(ID));
            }
        }

        private int year;
        public int Year
        {
            get
            {
                return year;
            }
            set
            {
                year = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChange(nameof(ID));
            }
        }

        private int quarter;
        public int Quarter
        {
            get
            {
                return quarter;
            }
            set
            {
                quarter = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChange(nameof(ID));
            }
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChange(nameof(ID));
            }
        }

        private int safetyScore;

        public int SafetyScore
        {
            get
            {
                return safetyScore;
            }
            set
            {
                safetyScore = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChange(nameof(ID));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChange(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: My prayers have been answered! Thank you so much for taking the time lay everything out in a concise, easy to understand way. The only piece I don't fully grasp is the Model, GetData() part. I don't know how to adapt that piece in order to retrieve data from a SQL Server instead of the dummy data. I use entity framework to generate my model as shown in my previous question. Could you please show me how should I approach it? Many thanks.

Comment: For MVVM, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593720/window-load-event-in-mvvm) post which demonstrates how OnLoad window event can bind to a command. In OnLoad command, you can get the data from SQL using entity framework.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I took a look at it but I just don't seem to figure this one out. I would have appreciated a more detailed example of how to pass | query the entities but I understand your time might be limited. Thank you again for all your help.